# I cant see root in my gradle to extract SHA key for google login .my android version is 4.2

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOE1C.png)

my android version is 4.2

Here it is gradle showing dependencies only

Iam done gradle configuration and jdk configuration

I've checked their version .working good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the elephant icon:

[image]

and type `signingReport` -> enter -> find the SHA-1 key.